# How to format fortran output in Maxima

Tags: formatting, output, indentation, maxima

I am using Maxima (aka Macsyma) to generate some coefficients and Maxima has to write the fortran representation of the expression in an external file for a python program to read out of.

I am using the following piece of code to write the coefficients down:

```
with_stdout ("An.txt",
    for n : 0 thru N do
        fortran(A[n]));
```

But unfortunately they get written down in the file `An.txt` exactly like this:

```
      exp(beta*t)*(-alpha*(beta**2*t**2+2*beta*t+2)*exp(-beta*t)*D/beta*
     1   *3+alpha*(beta*t+1)*exp(-beta*t)*D/beta**2-alpha**2*(beta**4*t*
     2   *4+4*beta**3*t**3+12*beta**2*t**2+24*beta*t+24)*exp(-beta*t)/be
     3   ta**5+2*alpha**2*(beta**3*t**3+3*beta**2*t**2+6*beta*t+6)*exp(-
     4   beta*t)/beta**4-alpha**2*(beta**2*t**2+2*beta*t+2)*exp(-beta*t)
     5   /beta**3+%c)
      alpha*(t-1)*t
      beta
      (2*(beta*D+3*alpha*beta*(t-1)*t)+alpha*t+alpha*(t-1))/A_0(t)/6.0E+
     1   0
```

yes, that's with a five(or six)-space indentation before every entry and with the numbers indicating a continuation of expression.

Any chance I can get a easier-to-read version of this? Every entry in one full line would be ideal. I have already tried the function `f90` but it prints out nothing and I have also tried to use `fortindent` and `fortspaces` but nothing changes (I might be using the wrong syntax for them, though).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use f90 after telling it to allow very long lines. Note that f90 is not loaded by default.

```
(%i1) load (f90) $
(%i2) :lisp (setq *f90-output-line-length-max* 1000000000)
1000000000
(%i2) A : makelist (expand ((foo + exp(bar*t))^n), n, [5, 10, 20]) $
(%i3) with_stdout ("A.txt", for e in A do f90(e));
(%o3)                                done
```

Note that you have to set the line length via Lisp; that's a wart. Here is the output I get:

```
$ cat A.txt
exp(5*bar*t)+5*foo*exp(4*bar*t)+10*foo**2*exp(3*bar*t)+10*foo**3*exp(2*bar*t)+5*foo**4*exp(bar*t)+foo**5
exp(10*bar*t)+10*foo*exp(9*bar*t)+45*foo**2*exp(8*bar*t)+120*foo**3*exp(7*bar*t)+210*foo**4*exp(6*bar*t)+252*foo**5*exp(5*bar*t)+210*foo**6*exp(4*bar*t)+120*foo**7*exp(3*bar*t)+45*foo**8*exp(2*bar*t)+10*foo**9*exp(bar*t)+foo**10
exp(20*bar*t)+20*foo*exp(19*bar*t)+190*foo**2*exp(18*bar*t)+1140*foo**3*exp(17*bar*t)+4845*foo**4*exp(16*bar*t)+15504*foo**5*exp(15*bar*t)+38760*foo**6*exp(14*bar*t)+77520*foo**7*exp(13*bar*t)+125970*foo**8*exp(12*bar*t)+167960*foo**9*exp(11*bar*t)+184756*foo**10*exp(10*bar*t)+167960*foo**11*exp(9*bar*t)+125970*foo**12*exp(8*bar*t)+77520*foo**13*exp(7*bar*t)+38760*foo**14*exp(6*bar*t)+15504*foo**15*exp(5*bar*t)+4845*foo**16*exp(4*bar*t)+1140*foo**17*exp(3*bar*t)+190*foo**18*exp(2*bar*t)+20*foo**19*exp(bar*t)+foo**20
$ wc A.txt
  3   3 856 A.txt
```

I see you have a `%c` in your output; maybe you need to substitute something for that in order to make the output acceptable to Python?

By the way, the fixed width with continuation characters is an artifact left over from the days of punch cards ....

Comment: I had that code working in python already (even with the `%c`) but it wasn't very clean and I reckon the chance of something going wrong (due to the many `if`s) was big. This is way better. About the punch cards thing, I think this is the only bad thing from maxima: it hasn't really evolved into a modern-day programming language!

Comment: @TomCho About the punch cards, actually Maxima is just trying to accommodate the "lowest common denominator" of Fortran compilers. The fixed-format 72 character line business is a Fortranism. I actually wrote programs on punch cards in the early 1980's ... good times.

Comment: Yes, but why not make it easier to switch from that to a more recent format? Or, actually, any formatting we want? Anyway, I'm glad the solution for this was easy, but eventually I know I'm going to end up having to migrate to sage because of such things.